# Programmatically find Eureka server host and port

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-eureka

I want to setup Eureka server for service registry and erueka clients that will get access rest api using the service registry from Eureka server. But we use mesos as our container management system and when we start the Eureka server we will not know which host and port it is running on. So there is an api that we can use that gives us the complete url where Eureka server will be running. Now all the examples for Eureka client that I have seen have hard coded the Eureka server in the config file. Is it possible for Eureka clients to use that api and get the url for Eureka server. 
 FYI: we are using spring boot and have our own DC and are not on any cloud

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer but if someone can confirm that will be great. I need to create my own EurekaClientConfigBean and override the following methods:

```
public void setEurekaServiceUrlPollIntervalSeconds(int eurekaServiceUrlPollIntervalSeconds)

List<String> getEurekaServerServiceUrls(String zone);
```

Comment: Yes, That' s correct. After creating this configuration you can use the same while initializing you EurekaClient beans. This should work.